# How to join a table where the table name is stored as a column value in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

To allow multiple payment gateways in my system I have a table of defined payment gateways (id, name, code) where `code` is the table name (for example 'paypal') containing a specific payment gateway transaction responses.

In my sql server query I want to join the transaction table for each gateway based on the value of this column.

Is this possible? If so, how?

In my query so far I am joining the payment gateway table based on the id of the chosen payment gateway for the specific seller (where `[s]` is the seller table):

```
INNER JOIN [payment_gateway] AS [pg] ON [s].[payment_gateway_id] = [pg].[id]
```

What I want to do is something like:

```
INNER JOIN {{[pg].[code]}} AS [payment_table] ON [payment_table].[order_id] = [order].[id]
```

Comment: (1) As you describe the solution, y ou would have to use dynamic SQL.  (2) This is a pretty bad database design.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right, this is a poor design choice. You should have one table for your transactions, and that table should state what the gateway is. Having a field in a table that tells you what table to look for causes all sorts of problems. You could achieve this with Dynamic SQL if you're doing a query for a single Gateway, however, if you're running a query with gateways, then you're going to need to do as Gordan suggested below; use lots of `LEFT JOIN`s (which is going to *probably* perform poorly).

Comment: So if I have a single transactions table, I would just store the payment gateway id and... a json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the join is dependant on the column value, I have decided to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the table:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [paypal] as [pp] on [pp].[quote_id] = [q].[id] and [pg].[code] = 'paypal'
```

It means I'll need to add this line for every new payment gateway that I integrate, but I'm ok with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT . . .,
       COALESCE(pg1.col pg2.col, . . .) as col
FROM seller s LEFT JOIN
     payment_gateway pg1 
     ON s.payment_gateway_id = pg1.id AND s.code = '1' LEFT JOIN
     payment_gateway pg2 
     ON s.payment_gateway_id = pg2.id AND s.code = '2' LEFT JOIN
     . . .
```

A `LEFT JOIN` is probably the most efficient way of handling this data in a single query.  A better data structure would have all the payment gateway information in a single table.